# writing own commands in Tex studio

Tags: dvi, dvi-mode

1. In Texstudio how to open my own window to write div my own Latex command?
2. Also, in Tex studio, how to run Latex and create a dvi file only, not PDF?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se, typically it should be one question per question but as they both look similar it should be fine. What do you mean by new command, a new command in your document code or a new command in texstudio?

Comment: (2) In tools menu, run LaTeX, not PDFLaTeX (1) Configure the editor? (penultimate menu). Is not clear at all what are you asking here ...

Comment: Thanks, James, I mean a new command in Tex studio .

Comment: Check  in Options → Configure Texworks  what are your options to make/modify menu options and shorcuts.